# Zeppelin - noteSelect in groovy

Tags: groovy, apache-zeppelin

I want to create a dynamic 'select' using groovy. 
The select scope should be the notebook.

Zeppelin Version: 0.8.0

The problem is that when I try to use `g.noteSelect` I get an exception.
After checking what are the available methods on `g` it is clear the `noteSelect` is not a `g` method.

How can I create a dynamic (notebook scope) Select with groovy?

My code:

```
%groovy

def tunnels =  ['c':'c','v':'v']
//g.noteSelect('SelectTunnel', 'None', tunnels)
print(org.apache.zeppelin.groovy.GObject.declaredMethods.findAll { !it.synthetic }.name)
```

output

```
class org.apache.zeppelin.groovy.GObject[html, startOutputType, toParamOptions, getAngularObject, angular, angularBind, angularBind, getInterpreterContextRunner, getInterpreterContextRunner, runNote, runNote, runAll, runAll, checkbox, checkbox, select, select, input, input, getGui, run, run, run, get, get, put, setProperty, getProperty, getProperties, table]
```

Comment: try `g.z.noteSelect('SelectTunnel', 'None', tunnels)`

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use scala (%spark) so I could use `z.noteSelect(..)`